# Showing a sequence is convergent using the ϵ-N definition

Tags: real-analysis

I have just shown that the sequence

$\lim\limits_{n \to ∞}$ $( n-\sqrt{n^2-n} )$ = $\frac{1}{2}$

by using the difference of two squares. However I am having difficulty showing it converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ using the $\epsilon$-N definition of convergence.

I start like this:

Let  $\epsilon$>0. Then let $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Then for all $n\geq N$, $|(n-\sqrt{n^2 -n}) -\frac{1}{2}| = ?= ...=\frac{1}{N} = \epsilon$

Therefore converges to $\frac{1}{2}$

I have been working through the [khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/series-calc/seq-conv-diverg-calc/v/proving-a-sequence-converges) videos on convergence but I cannot work out how their examples fit into mine and therefore fill my steps.
If anyone can explain my missing steps in detail I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** For proofs like this you don't take $N$ to be something and try to prove that it works. You have to **find** the $N$ which work.

Why did you pick $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$? This $N$ does work, but the key to the proof is how you found it wot work.

**Proof:** You need
$$|(n-\sqrt{n^2 -n}) -\frac{1}{2}| <\epsilon \Leftrightarrow  \\
\left| \frac{n}{n+\sqrt{n^2-n}}-\frac{1}{2} \right| < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow  \\
\frac{1}{2}\left| \frac{n-\sqrt{n^2-n}}{n+\sqrt{n^2-n}} \right|< \epsilon \Leftrightarrow  \\
\frac{1}{2}\left| \frac{n}{(n+\sqrt{n^2-n})^2} \right| <\epsilon $$

Now use the fact that 
$$\frac{1}{2}\left| \frac{n}{(n+\sqrt{n^2-n})^2} \right| < \frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}$$

Therefore, if you can make $\frac{1}{n} <\epsilon$ you get what you need.

**Important:** This is how we always reach the conclusion. Write 
$$|a_n - L| < \epsilon$$
and try to boil it down to something (which is implied by) 
$$n >\mbox{ something }$$

This tells you what your $N$ is..

Finally, you write the "nice" solution, which is your argument **backwards**:

Let $N$ be what you got at the last line, then write your algebraic manipulations backwards and get your stating line
$$|a_n-L|< \epsilon$$

Comment: Thank you so much this is so helpful! Can you quickly show me how you simplified |n/n+sqrt(n^2 -n) - 1/2| ?

Comment: @BTaylor That's a difference of two fractions, thus common denominator:)

Answer (score 0):

$|n-\sqrt{n^2-n}-\frac{1}{2}|$

$=|\frac{n}{n+\sqrt{n^2-n}}-\frac{1}{2}|$

$=|\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}}-\frac{1}{2}|$

$=|\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}}{2(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}})}|$

$=|\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{2(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}})^2}|$

$\leq|\frac{1}{n}|$

$\leq\varepsilon$

Comment: Between steps 2 and 3 what factor did you use to multiply? Tyvm by the way!

Comment: Also, can you explain the process/assumption behind steps 5 and 6?

Comment: Between steps 2 and 3 I use nothing to multiply but just reduce the fractions into the same denominators. Between steps 5 and 6 I use the assumptions that $N=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ and $n\geq N$.